# On save creating a dist folder in every created folder

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

Every time I create a folder with a file, on save it creates a dist folder. Is there any tslint feature that could cause this?

[Every folder has a 'dist' folder below it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arNwk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually configured in your `tsconfig.json`. There maybe additional configuration you have set in it. Usually the tsconfig.json `outDir` is usually configured like this:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    ...,
    "outDir": "dist"

}
```

Comment: Hi @LukeKasson, glad it helps! It would be much appreciated if you can upvote my answer or mark it as an accepted answer as well, that would mean a lot. Thank you very much! :)